# SSRProvider is not working in my NextJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

My app is built using NextJs with Typescript and using the react-bootstrap library for components. I keep getting an error that says
`When server rendering, you must wrap your application in an <SSRProvider> to ensure consistent ids are generated between the client and server.`

I tried to include the SSRProvider that comes with react-bootstrap, but it doesn't seem to be working no matter where I put it in my `_app.tsx` file. Anyone know how to resolve this? My UI keeps breaking when reloading the page.

```
import type { NextComponentType } from 'next';
import { AppContext, AppInitialProps, AppLayoutProps } from 'next/app';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../styles/theme';
import { SSRProvider } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MyApp: NextComponentType<AppContext, AppInitialProps, AppLayoutProps> = ({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppLayoutProps) => {
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page: ReactNode) => page);

  return (
      getLayout(
      <SSRProvider>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </SSRProvider>
      )
    )
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Did you try to wrapping higher, so you wrap MyApp?

Comment: @DamianBusz Can you specify where you mean? There's the MyApp declaration, props list, then return value type (AppLayoutProps). Not sure where else I can put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this by wrapping the entire return statement in the `<SSRProvider>` tag. Last time I tried that, I forgot to wrap the `getLayout()` statement in curly braces. Here is the code for anyone running into the same issue.

```
return (
      <SSRProvider>
      {getLayout(
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      )}
      </SSRProvider>
    )
```

Comment: Does server side rendering actually work with NextJS and React-bootstrap? Everything I tried indicated it doesn't; if a nextJS react component uses another component that takes useState (e.g. react-bootstrap button), the parent needs 'use client' at the top. Even the Next-ui says it only works on client side rendering. I think this defeats the purpose of nextJS ssr, if you are forced to build custom primitives on the backside that are different from the frontend components. So with the 2 sentence description for the SSR Provider tag, and the other docs, I have no idea what this tag does.

Comment: I confirm, with Next13 & app directory, there is a hudge problem about SSR & SSRProvider for react-bootstrap, need answers about that from the core team